# Filtering using RegEx within Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I am using the below plugin to fetch tweets and display them.

http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/

Within the plugin is a filter feature, and the below regex filters out all tweets on the account which are replies:

```
filter: function(t){ return ! /^@\w+/.test(t.tweet_raw_text); }
```

I wish to now build on this filter to only display tweets which contain the hashtag '#capetowntrains'

Can anyone assist me with the correctly formed RegEx statement?

Thanks for the help

Regards

Devin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should just need to change it to this

```
filter: function(t){ 
    return (! /^@\w+/.test(t.tweet_raw_text)) && (/#capetowntrains/.test(t.tweet_raw_text)); 
}
```

We only keep things that are not replies and also contain #capetowntrains.

EDIT: and if you want it to be case insensitive (note the added `i`)

```
filter: function(t){ 
    return (! /^@\w+/.test(t.tweet_raw_text)) && (/#capetowntrains/i.test(t.tweet_raw_text)); 
}
```

Comment: Hi CaffGeek. Thanks for your response. I need the regex to still remove the replies in addition to filtering out the hashtag. Can you please combine the 2.

Comment: @user1434739, Sorry, that wasn't clear in the question.  Fixed.